# Prevent a JQuery .click event from activating if its a drag?

Tags: jquery

I have an image slider, that you can click and drag the image to view the next one.

I also have the following code which will launch a "FancyBox" control when the image is clicked.

```
            $(".sliderimagefancybox").click(function(e) {
                var url = $(this).attr('src');
                var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
                var content = '<img src="' + url + '" rel="'+ rel + '" />';
                $.fancybox({
                    'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
                    'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
                    'speedIn'       :   600, 
                    'speedOut'      :   200, 
                    'overlayShow'   :   false,
                    'content' : content
                });
            });
```

The trouble is, if a user clicks and drags the image, and the click is released over the image still, then the click event above is triggered.

How can I get this to ignore drags?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".sliderimagefancybox").on("mousedown", function(e) {

  this.tOut = setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("tOut");
    var content = '<img src="' + this.src + '" rel="'+ this.rel + '" />';
    $.fancybox({
      'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
      'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
      'speedIn'       :   600, 
      'speedOut'      :   200, 
      'overlayShow'   :   false,
      'content' : content
    });
  }, 240);

}).on("mousemove", function(){

  clearTimeout( this.tOut ); // Don't activate fancybox if mousemoved

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can see how it should work, however the click function doesn't work at all now. No errors in the console either. I'll try to figure it out.